# Determine if the vector field is conservative; if it is find a potential function for the vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The vector field in question is $F(x,y)=3x^2y\mathbf i+x^3\mathbf j$.

I feel like the answer is $f(x.y)=x^3y$.

However most problems that I have done similar to this have an extra component. Could anyone confirm, or point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Don't use the title and the question's body as one.

Comment: What is $\dfrac{df}{dx}$? What is $\dfrac{df}{dy}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}((3x^2)y) = 3x^2 = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^3)$$

so $\vec{F}$ is a conservative vector field.   Integrating the $\mathbf{i}$ component with respect to $x$, we obtain

$$\int (3x^2)y dx = x^3y + \phi(y)$$

where $\phi$ is some function of $y$.  Differentiating the above with respect to $y$ yields

$$x^3 + \phi'(y) = x^3$$

Hence, $\phi(y) = K$ where $K$ is a constant, so $ f(x, y) = x^3y + K$ is a potential function.

Comment: Downvoter, if you see something wrong, point it out.

Answer (score 1):

A well-known theorem is that a vector field is conservative if and only if it is a gradient vector field.

As you say, if $\operatorname{f}(x,y) = x^3y$ then

$$\nabla\operatorname{f} = 3x^2y \, {\bf i} + x^3 \, {\bf j}$$

Hence, the vector field $3x^2y \, {\bf i} + x^3 \, {\bf j}$ is conservative.

Answer (score 0):

We verify that $\nabla \times F =0$, so solution to $\nabla g=F$ exist. As you mentioned, one such $g$ is indeed $x^3y$. The only solution of the equation $\nabla g=0$ is a constant function, hence the final solution is $x^3y+C$, $C$  is an arbitrary constant.